# How to add Maven of IBM Cloud API for Java to Android Studio?

Tags: java, api

The code given is this:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.ibm.watson</groupId>
     <artifactId>ibm-watson</artifactId>
     <version>8.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using intellij change the files explorer view to project then right click on the project file,you will see an option saying add framework.Click on that and select maven after that open the pom.xml file and add the dependencies tag then you can add your dependency there...hope that helps you